Attempting to use a template function with a single non-type template parameter
I tried a version of the prorgam that avoids recursion:
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
constexpr int factorial()
{
  int value = 1; // 0! = 1
  for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
  {
    value *= i;
  }
  return value;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << factorial<5>() << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}

It works, and returns 120, as expected.
However, when I try to use recursion, it fails with compile-time errors.
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
constexpr int factorial()
{
  if (N == 0) return 1;
  return N * factorial<N - 1>();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << factorial<5>() << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}

I'll detail the compile-time errors later...
I tried the recursion version, and expected it to give me 120, as did the non-recursive version.
I'm using XCode on an iMac, with GCC++17. The recursion version gave me the following errors:
Factorial Template
/Users/bryanhiggs/C++ Development/Factorial Template/Factorial Template/main.cpp
/Users/bryanhiggs/C++ Development/Factorial Template/Factorial Template/main.cpp unable to execute command: Illegal instruction: 4

/Users/bryanhiggs/C++ Development/Factorial Template/Factorial Template/main.cpp clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
diagnostic msg: /var/folders/zv/nww97t6d3yl_xskx2_k5_jlr0000gn/T/main-5df374.cpp
diagnostic msg: /var/folders/zv/nww97t6d3yl_xskx2_k5_jlr0000gn/T/main-5df374.sh
diagnostic msg: Crash backtrace is located in
diagnostic msg: /Users/bryanhiggs/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/clang_<YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMSS>_<hostname>.crash
diagnostic msg: (choose the .crash file that corresponds to your crash)
diagnostic msg: 

********************


Is this a bug in GCC++17, or am I misunderstanding something?

Your base-case doesn't work. The compiler stamps out a function for N = 0 like so:
template <>
constexpr int factorial<0>()
{
  if (0 == 0) return 1;
  return N * factorial<0-1>();
}

Of course, it does return 1, but the function still contains the expression factorial<N - 1>() which must therefore be stamped out.
There are two ways of solving this:
Using if constexpr
template <int N>
constexpr int factorial()
{
  // A compile-time if which drops the non-hitting block immediately
  if constexpr (N == 0) return 1;
  else return N * factorial<N - 1>();
}

Use a specialization for the base case
// General function for any N other than 0
template <int N>
constexpr int factorial()
{
  return N * factorial<N - 1>();
}

// Specialization for N=0
template<>
constexpr int factorial<0>
{
  return 1;
}


Thank you. I'm not sure what 'stamped out' means, but I understand the use of constexpr to enforce a compile-time if statement. Although it's a new concept to me, having taken a break from C++ for a while.
